# Synchronized two frequency source seems to have phase drift

Tags: rf

I have two arbitrary waveform generators which are synchronized at the external but shared 10 MHz clock. My research experiment importantly uses phase-sensitive signals.
The problem I observed is that even if they are set the same nominated frequency (for example, 30 MHz), there exist a frequency offset which makes a very slow phase shift.
I want to maintain the same phase (no phase drift) for days and weeks, but I realize it fundamentally difficult.

To avoid this problem via synthesizing all the signal in the same instruments, I needs 3 channels for I/Q and local oscillator. However, my arbitrary waveform generator has only two channels so that I am using two synchronized AWG.

The speed of phase drift is 10 degree for an hour, which corresponds to 8 uHz.
I am not sure I can compensate this frequency difference by nominating the frequency to be above or below.

The AWGs used are  (1) AWG : Agilent 81150A, (2) AFG : Tektronix AFG1062. I/Q are generated in AWG, and the baseband LO from AFG. Frequencies are both in 30 MHz.

Comment: I am sorry that I omitted the information. I added here that (1) AWG : Agilent 81150A, (2) AFG : Tektronix AFG1062. I/Q are generated in AWG, and the baseband LO from AFG. Frequencies are both in 30 MHz. I could make a frequency offset -9 uHz in AWG approximately, which now minimizes phase drifts.

Comment: This seems weird. If the two generators are using the same clock there should not be any drift. I guess I would first double-check everything about how they are synchronized. Is there some setting to force them to use the external clock input?

Comment: 8u/30M<3E-13, this drift is way too small for the generators not to be synced. It may be some rounding in the frequency settings, can you find the size of accumulators? 3E-13 should roughly 1bit out of 43

Comment: I would try some other frequencies, for instance  5 MHz, 10 MHz, 20 MHz, 32 MHz, 32.768 MHz

Comment: I've seen exactly the same thing on pricey (but old) 40 GHz microwave generators with one locked to the other (Anritsu 68369B and HP 83640A), so concur that it's unlikely to be a problem with locking and most likely just an implementation difference between the devices as the answer states. It's been a while since I looked at the data but in that case the frequency difference might have even varied a little bit over time.

Comment: Thank everyone. I configured a simple phase detector with mixer, and have watched. It is lucky that the movement I have seen have been constant so far, such that-11 uHz forward compensation works for my range of time span. Still I have no certainty that the frequency offset is permanent or temporary (some dynamics with disturbance). I continue to record the movement. I'll try with other frequency (more rational or binary relation with oscillator), and will inform here with any results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that AWGs are often, well usually, binary based internally.

The attitude of many AWG manufacturers is that once you can approximate your desired frequency to the nearest μHz, it's 'close enough', and that nobody will notice the error. This is reasonable for standalone operation, but as you've found out, no good when you try to synchronise two generators that are built differently.

Unfortunately, some get down to whole Hz before they give up and use a binary fraction below that, some stop at kHz, some go down to nHz, some just divide their 100 MHz timebase all the way down in binary. This means that any two arbitrary AWGs are unlikely to synchronise when running from the same external standard. It may not be obvious from the data sheet what the internal structure of any particular one is.

One way to get round the problem is to use AWGs of the same part number from the same manufacturer. Then there's an excellent chance that they will use the same hardware, with the same approximations.

If you can't source another AWG and you're not committed to any specific frequency, then experiment with different settings. Some may well be exact. You would need some inkling of the factors used in the different AWGs for this to be practical, the search space of possible settings would be prohibitive to do it blind. The data sheets might hint at what factors they use.

RF signal generators will often be exact decimal rather than binary. If you can figure out whether either of your AWGs is producing an exact frequency, then use this one against an RF sig gen.

It's not impossible to make a decimal based AWG, it just requires more thought, and a little more hardware, than a binary based one. For instance, one binary ASIC based fractional-N synthesiser that I worked on had a 1.6777216 MHz reference clock to get 0.1 Hz exact resolution. It was made by a 104.8576 MHz oscillator fracN locked to the 10 MHz reference, fractionally divided by 62.5. Too much like hard work! Its successor used an FPGA to implement a fully decimal fracN, so back to sensible reference frequencies. I bought a cheap DDS/AWG (FY6800) recently which appears to be fully binary all the way down from a 250 MHz top clock.